# ruby quiz - re-assigning array values with while-loop

Tags: ruby

I have this example from an "easy" ruby quiz. I want to re-assign the value of an array (e.g. word1[0]) if it equals (==) the value of array1 to the value of array2. Take a look at the code so it is obvious:

```
array1 = Array.new
array1 = ('A'..'Z').to_a

array2 = Array.new
array2 = ('A'..'Z').to_a
array2 = array2.rotate(2)

puts "enter a word:"
word1 = gets.chomp
word1 = word1.upcase.split(//)

n = 0

word1.each do
  while n < 26
    if word1[n] == array1[n]
      word1[n] = array2[n]
    end
    n += 1
  end
end

puts word1   # This word should now be "encoded" and not easy to read.
```

I have tried this code and it kind of randomly changes only 1-2 letters of any word that i type in (gets.chomp).

Hence word1 is an Array I am expecting, that each element (letter) gets compared to array1[0] and if it equals then it will be re-assigned to the value of array2[0]. If word1[0] and array1[0] are not equal then the value of 'n' changes +1 and the block is run again.

NOTE: I don't want to have an easy formula for this problem, I want to really understand what is going on here and WHY my each-iteration does not work as i expect. So if you can answer this question at "my level of knowledge" that would be really awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to answer my question with a very simple approach:

```
def cypher(input_array)

  normal_array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
  cypher_array = normal_array.rotate(2)
  awesome_cyphered_array = []

  input_array.each do |element|
    0.upto(25) do |i|
      case element
        when normal_array[i]
          awesome_cyphered_array << cypher_array[i]
      end
    end
  end
  puts awesome_cyphered_array.join  
end

# START of my program
puts "Enter a sentence, it will be cyphered!"
sentence = gets.chomp
length = sentence.length
sentence_as_array = sentence.upcase.split(//).reverse!

make_it_an_array = []

1.upto(length) do 
  make_it_an_array << sentence_as_array.pop
end

cypher(make_it_an_array)
```

Comment: Please don't take this comment as offensive, but: (1) shorter does not mean simplier, (2) it is still far more complicated than it should be (you use upto/case/when in very weird way and also string->array is a one liner without a loop, etc..), (3) this code actually **does not** answer your question - it answers your problem that generated the question, but not the question, (4) I don't really need that 15rep from 'accepted' answer, but I think it's quite inappropriate to reassign points after a few months - you seemed quite happy with previous answers, so why jump back in time? ;)

Comment: Dont delete your answer/code, just polish it better! remove that strange string-to-array conversion (String class has 'each_char' method) and change the upto(25)-case-when to some reasonable lookup, either with a single simple hash or 'index' method. Really, there's no need to loop everywhere ;)

Comment: you are right, my answer can still be refactored. but it is easier to understand for me as a ruby beginner, and that is simply why i wanted to post it. i will refactor it within the next days. thanks for the positive feedback! thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

First, you forgot to reset the counter N between consecutive the words. You set the N to zero, then you start to iterate over the words.

So, in the overview, your algo behaves like that:

For first word, the N iterates over 0..25
For second word, the N starts with 26, and DOES NOT iterate at all
For third word, the N starts with 26, and does not iterate
..
etc.

So, for complete starters, do:

```
array1 = Array.new
array1 = ('A'..'Z').to_a

array2 = Array.new
array2 = ('A'..'Z').to_a
array2 = array2.rotate(2)

puts "enter a word:"
word1 = gets.chomp
word1 = word1.upcase.split(//)     # <-- note that you REPLACE the input string
                                   # with an sequence of STRINGS produced by SPLIT

word1.each do                      # for each STRING in the SEQUENCE
  n = 0
  while n < 26                     # scan all 26 letters from ARRAY
    if word1[n] == array1[n]       # ... WTF
      word1[n] = array2[n]
    end
    n += 1
  end
end
```

Now you will keep the letter scanning at least running in the same way for every one word. However, this will not work as expected either, but wholly different reason.

How do you use the N actually?

```
    if word1[n] == array1[n]
      word1[n] = array2[n]
    end
```

So, you read Nth WORD from the SEQUENCE
.. and compare it against Nth LETTER from the array1.

Is it really what you wanted to do? Quite not.

You most probably wanted to replace every letter in WORD along with letter-pairs formed by the two arrays.

So, instead, you wanted to:

- read the Nth letters from WORD1
- then check **at what index** it is in the array1
- and then read the substitution letter from that index
- and then write the letter back at Nth place in WORD:

  ```
  letter = word[position]
  letterindex = array1.index(letter)
  substitution = array2[letterindex]
  word[position] = subsitution
  ```

You can compact it into oneliner too:

```
 -- loop
    -- loop2
      word[position] = array2[array1.index(word[position])]
```

However, please note that I say now `position`, not `N`. You've used `N` as range 0..25, which means the index of the letter in ARRAY.

But, for inspecting the word's letters, you need to iterate **over the word's letters**. How long is the word? Certainly, not 0..25!

Also note the subtle change: `word` instead of `word1`. I say "word" and "word's letters", not "arrayofwords". Originally, you used `N` also to read Nth word from the sequence, let's keep it. But as we need to iterate over word's leters, a different variable is needed, 'say `position`:

```
n = 0

arrayOfWords.each do

    word = arrayOfWords[n]

    position = 0

    while position < word.length
        letter = word[position]
        letterindex = array1.index(letter)
        substitution = array2[letterindex]
        word[position] = subsitution
        position += 1
    end

    n += 1
end
```

Note how `N` stays and only increases with each word, and how `position` is reset everytime to zero, to iterate over actual length of the **current word**.

In Ruby, this is overly elaborate way to do that. Ruby has a lot of nice tricks that can shorten the code. For example, the `each` method is not only a loop. It actually *gives you each word**, you don't need the N at all:

```
arrayOfWords.each do |word|

    position = 0

    while position < word.length
       word[position] = array2[array1.index(word[position])]
       position += 1
    end

end
```

Note how I added "word" in bars || to the `each` call.
In similar way you actually could get rid of the `position` too, but that would in turn make the code shorter but much harder to read/understand.

Comment: no no no this is so much wrong:( sorry, I've misread one of your original lines. Please wait a while, I'll update the post

Comment: at least you already made me understand to reset my counter between iterations!

Comment: I've updated the post, and I've renamed the variables so it's now clear what-is-what. Although I've included almost full solution, I suggest you try writing your own from scratch afterwards:) have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the same "counter" `n` to check two different arrays, try this:

**EDIT**
According to your comments, since you need only so scramble, here is a possible way:

```
array1 = ('A'..'Z').to_a
array2 = ('A'..'Z').to_a.shuffle

puts "enter a word:"
word1 = gets.chomp
word1 = word1.upcase.split(//)

n = 0

word1.each do
  word1[n] = array2[n]
  n +=1
end

puts word1
```

It will always generate a different input, even if you use the same word, because of the `shuffle` in your `array2`

Comment: I run your code and it has the same outcome as mine. Try run your code and you will se my problem.

Comment: input: HELLO; output:JGNNQ because of H=J, E=G L=N, L=N, O=Q;

Comment: I just want to have it encoded. I am already trying with 2 counters (n, t) thanks to your advice and it looks better.

Comment: I run your code now, the outcome is still not satisfying me in my understanding of Arrays. I see what you did and it works BUT it is something else than my requirements. Let me define my problem again: If element 0 from Array word1 equals element 0 from Array array1 THEN element 0 from Array word1 is re-assigned to element 0 from Array array2. And I HAVE TO iterate through all elements of array1.

Comment: I get it but in this situation the word should be something like `ABCDEF...`, it will be really improbable to have the same letters, in sequence, in the alphabet and in the word you type